# Issue using std::find to check strings against a vector of strings

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I'm a C++ rookie, and having trouble with grasping some concepts, specifically with std::find in a while loop, checking an array.

I've got a bit of a PHP background, but am very new to the C++/lower level language. My specific issues are towards the end of the program where I have the while (check >> word){} loop. Visual basic is giving me an error on my std::find as well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    //Open the dictionary file(it is called words.txt).
    ifstream myFile;
    myFile.open("dictionary.txt");
    //Define a vector of strings called words.
    std::vector<string> dictionary;
    //For each word in the dictionary file
    string word;
    while (myFile >> word){
        //Append the word to the words vector.
        dictionary.push_back(word);
    }
    //Open the file to be checked(the file is specified on the command line)
    ifstream check;
    check.open(argv[2]);
    //For each word in that file
    while (check >> word){
        //check vector dictionary to see if check >> word exists
        if (std::find(dictionary.begin(), dictionary.end(), word)){
            //If the word is not contained in the dictionary vector print the word.
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I apologize if this has been answered, but I've looked at a few threads, and I'll keep looking through more until I get it, but I'm still a bit lost. I'll keep trying to solve my own problem as well!

Thank you for any help!

Edit: Visual basic was giving an intellisense error; however that went away when I changed my while loop to this

```
while (check >> word){
    //check vector dictionary to see if check >> word exists
    if (std::find(dictionary.begin(), dictionary.end(), word) == dictionary.end()){
        //If the word is not contained in the dictionary vector print the word.
        cout << word << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: "is giving me an error"...

Comment: *"Visual basic is giving me an error"* Wait, basic?

Comment: `std::find` returns an iterator, that is not guaranteed to be "testable" (convertible to a `bool`).

Comment: @dyp: And in cases that it is (convertible to bool), its usage as such is almost certainly not useful (since it's probably a pointer into an array, and all results are going to evaluate to true, even the end iterator).

Comment: Note that you can `std::sort` your `dictionary`, and then use a `binary_search` (which btw returns a `bool`).

Comment: @dyp: or using a `std::map`.

Comment: I blanked, I mean't visual studio >_<.

Is there a benefit to using std::sort and binary or std::map? I'll soak up all this knowledge and really appreciate the help from ya'll!

Comment: @Jarod42 Non-contiguous storage and larger memory footprint :( This program only inserts once into a `map` and does not require the fixed address of the elements a `map` guarantees. Measure, but I bet the vector will be faster.

Comment: Note that if your question does not need to depend on outside resources, those dependencies should be eliminated. If your question is solely about using `std::find`, you can show it doesn't work as you expect merely by doing a `push_back()` of a single known string and then show you can't get a test to work for finding that string.  No iostreams or dictionary.txt and you can have a ["Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Also, here's a PDF [on std::set vs std::vector](http://lafstern.org/matt/col1.pdf).

Comment: @Jacob The idea of either approach is that you spend O(N*logN) time for insertion/sorting, and later can perform a lookup in O(logN) time for each word (or magic hash tables with O(N) average plus O(1) average). Whether or not that's faster -- had to be measured. Especially for small dictionaries, a linear lookup might be faster than a binary search.

Comment: @dyp: and OP may also use `std::set_difference` if both vectors are sorted :-)

Comment: To elaborate a bit on Kerrek's short comment: It is very useful or even required to include *what* error occurred in your question, since that typically already indicates (often somewhat cryptic) what the issue is. Also, it'd be nice if you clearly stated what your specific problem is. There is this "is giving me an error [...] as well" which hints at another error that I could not find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You condition should be:

```
std::find(dictionary.begin(), dictionary.end(), word) == dictionary.end()
```

Note that in your case, you may use a `map` instead and then use

```
dictionary.count(word) == 0
```

Comment: is there a reason to use != over ==, if I'm looking for words that are not in vector dictionary, rather than words that are?

Answer (score 2):

I think one of your biggest problems is your mindset that C++ is a lower level language. You're taking rather the long way around on some of these things, and in the process making your own life quite a bit more difficult.

I'd probably do the job more like this:

```
std::ifstream in("dictionary.txt");

// read all the words from the file:
std::vector<std::string> dictionary{std::istream_iterator<std::string>(in),
                                    std::istream_iterator<std::string>() };

// If the words might not already be sorted, sort them:
// std::sort(dictionary.begin(), dictionary.end());

// open the file to check:
std::ifstream check(argv[2]);

// print out the words that aren't in the dictionary:
std::copy_if(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(check), 
             std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
             std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"),
             [&](std::string const &word) { 
                 return !std::binary_search(dictionary.begin(), dictionary.end(), word);
             });
```

This will typically have a substantial speed advantage, because it's using a binary search instead of a linear search through the dictionary.

Comment: It's a bit lower than the PHP I'm used too haha. 

Thank you for this though, interesting to see how you can write it in another way! Seems a bit more advanced/different than what we've gone over in class.

Comment: Though short, the `Xstream_iterator` approach is not appreciated by everyone.

Comment: @dyp: 'tis true; some fail to appreciate it--but it *is* a failure on their part! :-)

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
int len = dictionary.size();
bool flag = true;
for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    if(dictionary[i] == word) {
        flag = false;
        break;
    }
}
if(flag)
    cout<<word<<"\n";
else
;
```

Comment: Is there a benefit to writing it this way over the way written by myself/Jarod above?

Comment: Not any in particular, other than easy to understand.

Comment: I find this harder to understand since I have to read the explicit loop and understand its individual parts. `std::find` is additional vocabulary, but IMHO useful and general enough to be learned/known.